# C#. Проблема с else

Tags: c#, циклы, if

Возможно это самый тупой вопрос, который вы видели, но все же.
Проблема в том, что конструкция else срабатывает, когда идущий перед ней if дает true и печатается несколько раз. В чем причина того, что он повторяется несколько раз, я предполагаю, но почему срабатывает каждый раз? Я мог бы убрать else и забыть, так как необязательно выводить сообщение "Таких элементов нет", но этот вопрос просто не дает покоя. Как можно реализовать правильное выполнение?

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("Массив из 10 рандомных элементов:");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
arr[i] = rnd.Next(-200, 200);
Console.Write("{0,4} ", arr[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Все элементы массива, оканчивающиеся нулем:");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
if (arr[i] % 10 == 0)
Console.Write("{0,4} ", arr[i]);
else
Console.Write("Таких элементов нет");
}
```

Выводит в консоль:

```
Массив из 10 рандомных элементов:
  92  -93  194 -166   60  143  -14  -80 -122   47
-------------------------------------------------------
Все элементы массива, оканчивающиеся нулем:
Таких элементов нетТаких элементов нетТаких элементов нетТаких элементов нет  60 Таких элементов нетТаких элементов нет -80 Таких элементов нетТаких элементов нет
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] % 10 == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0,4} ", arr[i]);
    found = true;
  }
}
if (!found)
  Console.WriteLine("Таких элементов нет");
```